# Eclipse UTF-8-weird characters

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, encoding, utf-8

I am writing a program in java with Eclipse IDE, and i want to write my comments in Greek. So i changed the encoding from Window->Preferences->General->Content Types->Text->Java Source File, to UTF-8. The comments in my code are ok but when i run my program some words contains weird characters e.g **San Germ�n** (*San Germán*). If i change the encoding to ISO-8859-1, all are ok when i run the program but the comments in my code are not(weird characters !). So, what is going wrong with it?

Edit: My program is in java swing and the weird characters with UTF-8 are Strings in cells of a JTable.

**EDIT(2):** Ok, i solve my problem i keep the UTF-8 encoding for java file but i change the encoding of the strings. `String k = new String(myStringInByteArray,ISO-8859-1);`

Comment: Where is "San Germán"? In a comment? In a String literal? In a property file? In a text file?

Comment: It is in a cell in a JTable!(not in comments)

Comment: The question is: where does the STring come from. Is is hard-coded as a String literal in your sources, or do you read it from a file, or from a database, before displaying it in your JTable. Show us your source code.

Comment: Are you sure that those characters are UTF-8? Maybe they are UTF-16. Since you found encoding that works leave it be.

Comment: @JB Nizet, I read it from a database. I read the database file byte to byte.

Comment: @ DjDexter5GHz I tried to change encoding to UTF-16 but it doesn't works...

Comment: So you're saying that the encoding of your Java source file changes the way a String read from the database is displayed on screen?  That's extremely surprising. In the end, the byte-code should be the same whatever the encoding of the source file is. What do you mean by "reading the database file"? I repeat: show us your source code.

Comment: In general there is no good reason to get bytes from a database, if the data is really a string. "I read the database file byte to byte" means it is very likely that the reading from database does not give you UTF-8, but ISO-8859-1. You should check if the database (and the table, and the column) is configured as Unicode to begin with, and if it is, then make sure you get the "read the database" right.

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely due to the compiler not using the correct character encoding when reading your source.  This is a very common source of error when moving between systems.

The typical way to solve it is to use plain ASCII (which is identical in both Windows 1252 and UTF-8) and the "\u1234" encoding scheme (unicode character 0x1234), but it is a bit cumbersome to handle as Eclipse (last time I looked) did not transparently support this.

The property file editor *does*, though, so a reasonable suggestion could be that you put all your strings in a property file, and load the strings as resources when needing to display them.  This is also an excellent introduction to Locales which are needed when you want to have your application be able to speak more than one language.